# Cannot use SQLCMD

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sqlcmd

I have started SQL Server in single user mode like this: `c:\....\sqlservr -m`

When I try to connect to it with `SQLCMD -E`, I get the following error:

```
Msg 18461, Level 14, State 1, Server SERVERNAME, Line 1
Login failed to user 'USER\Name'. Reason: Server is in single user mode. Only one administrator can connect at this time.
```

The user I am logged onto the server as is a domain administrator.

Before I tried this, the user I am logged on as had nothing to do with this SQL server. (I am in fact, trying to create a new SA as we don't know what the current password is)

**Edit**

It seems that even if I do:

```
c:\....\sqlservr -m"sqlcmd"
```

I am still getting the above error. I am not sure if there are other `SQLCMD` calls happening from elsewhere.

Comment: Being a domain admin might not have any effect on login rights. Since SS2008, local administrators group [is no longer added](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc281849(v=sql.100).aspx) into to sysadmin role without user interaction.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This case is explicitly called out in [Connect to SQL Server When System Administrators Are Locked Out](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd207004.aspx):

> When you start an instance of SQL Server in single-user mode, first stop the SQL Server Agent service. Otherwise, SQL Server Agent might connect first and prevent you from connecting as a second user.
>
> When you use the -m option with sqlcmd or SQL Server Management Studio, you can limit the connections to a specified client application. For example, `-m"sqlcmd"` limits connections to a single connection and that connection must identify itself as the sqlcmd client program. Use this option when you are starting SQL Server in single-user mode and an unknown client application is taking the only available connection. To connect through the Query Editor in Management Studio, use `-m"Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio - Query"`.

Comment: You can try to use `netstat` and see who is connected to the SQL listening port to help you narrow down the search space.

Answer (score 7):

Here's a potential syntax wrinkle.  Even though the [MS documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd207004(v=sql.110).aspx), as @RemusRasanu pointed out, says to use `-m"sqlcmd"`, like so:

> For example, -m"sqlcmd" limits connections to a single connection and
>   that connection must identify itself as the sqlcmd client program. Use
>   this option when you are starting SQL Server in single-user mode and
>   an unknown client application is taking the only available connection.

There's some evidence that the quotes in the parameter value prevent it from working as expected.  I was having issues getting connected using single-user mode, and removing the quotes from the startup parameter, i.e. using `-mSQLCMD` instead of `-m"sqlcmd"` worked for me.  I tried it both ways a couple different times to verify that there was a causal relationship, and that seems to be the case.  Maybe it's some sort of buggy edge case, but it worked for me.

You can see the difference in the SQL logs as, well.  For example:

```
2015-06-30 17:13:41.89 Server      Registry startup parameters: 
     -d c:\Prog[...]\master.mdf
     -e c:\Prog[...]\ERRORLOG
     -l c:\Prog[...]\mastlog.ldf
     -m "SQLCMD"
```

versus

```
2015-06-30 17:13:41.89 Server      Registry startup parameters: 
     -d c:\Prog[...]\master.mdf
     -e c:\Prog[...]\ERRORLOG
     -l c:\Prog[...]\mastlog.ldf
     -m SQLCMD
```

I stole this from this ServerFault answer, so go there and vote it up if you found it helpful: https://serverfault.com/a/338294/3183