# With LocalAdmin become sysadmin SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sqlcmd, role

I am a local Admin on my machine.  My account wasn't added when SQL Server was installed, and I don't want to have to reinstall SQL Server.  It worked until I tried to log and run the commands via SQLCMD or SSMS.  I got the error message

> Login failed for user `<Machine_Name>/<Windows Name>`. Reason: Server is in single user mode. Only one administrator can connect at this time...

I found [this blog](http://sqlserver-help.com/2013/12/06/help-how-to-fix-error-reason-server-is-in-single-user-mode-only-one-administrator-can-connect-at-this-time/) and added the application name after the m switch.  But no dice, I still get the above error.  The User Account looks fine I guess, I am an Administrator.

Also, 
  I had to start the cmd prompt as an Admin to start sqlserver in single user mode, or else I couldn't have access to the log files that the instance was using and it was giving me an error to that.  So I ran the cmd prompt as admin. But still, I am the same admin trying to run SQLCMD or SSMS.  It shouldn't be telling me there is already an admin logged in, because I am that admin.  What am I missing?

This is on SQLExpress.

Answer (score 1):

For such a situation we have made use of PSExec utility to get regain access on the SQL server.

You can download the utility from [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx) , extract and copy the exe file to the drive location from where you can run below command.

Once downloaded you need to open the cmd with admin and run below:

```
PsExec -s -i "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\Ssms.exe"
```

The path above may vary, like for one of our SQL 2k8 , we found the path to be:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\Ssms.exe"
```

This will make you connect to the current via sever Windows Authentication, and the username is hard-coded as NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM.

YOu can create the required login from here:

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar when first using [DAC (Dedicated Admin Connection).](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/diagnostic-connection-for-database-administrators?view=sql-server-ver15)  In my case it turns out that I used SSMS to grab the one and only DAC, I did not realize it for sometime.

For example if you grabbed the connection with SSMS, you can close and re-open SSMS to release the connection.

As a last resort rebooting the server, will release whatever has the DAC connection.

See also ["When you start an instance of SQL Server in single-user mode, first stop the SQL Server Agent service. Otherwise, SQL Server Agent might connect first and prevent you from connecting as a second user."](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/50798/21924)